# preserving git repo state during compilation

Tags: git, unit-testing, continuous-integration

Is there a well known git workflow for compiling the current uncommitted code state, so that code/data edits can continue while an async compile/deploy/test is in progress?

It would be like (efficiently!) stashing then cloning all current repos stashed state to a place that the compilers actually run against.  If compilation or testing fails, you should be able to navigate from your current editing state to the state that a build job failed in.

There might be multiple async jobs like this running concurrently: (ie: release/debug).

Comment: So you're talking about something like a FUSEd ~commitfs~ that represents the filesystem as it appears in a commit -- so you could `git stash -[uka]` and mount that commit somewhere?  Educated guess says a clone --shared --single-branch would be very acceptably fast, maybe somebody's built an FS like that, haven't checked.

Comment: Correct; except... the build cycle clones the current uncommitted state - that is in the editors. The issue is that it is currently a race condition to continue to edit code while build/deploy/test cycles are underway.  If a cycle that takes a half hour begins, you should be able to just move on to editing code, and get notification when a cycle completes.  Note that this also means that concurrently created build turds are an issue too.

Comment: Hence, cloning a stash.  If you want identical content, `git stash -a; git clone -s --shared . ../build stash; git stash pop` is the easiest to implement, you could get better performance for the same results directly with the plumbing.  (in case it isn't obvious, this is keyboard-to-editbox, but I expect it's substantially correct and usable)

Comment: build runs in the background and comes after an atomic stash/clone/stashpop or else it wipes out work done while the build ran.  during the build, the developer may be doing stashing of his own.  stash has the virtue of not leaving a mess to be cleaned up with "git rebase -i" before being pushed back out.

Comment: stash is unsafe because the stash/clone/unstash can get killed before unstash finishes.  so, I took a quite different approach that seems to work well:  two directories, src and turds. remake script above them both does "rsync -avz src/* turds; ( cd turds; scons & )".  This ensures that there are no build turds in the src directories, and a consistent snapshot is compiled in the background.  This is because it doesn't reach "scons &" unless the rsync completed.  Something more baroque would be required to gracefully handle overlapping builds.

Comment: what about a second remote / repository? one that's used only by you. you can easily manage multiple remotes with git

Answer (score 0):

A continuous integration server (such as Jenkins, TeamCity or Travis CI) will do all the management and bookkeeping for you. You can set it up to compile each commit, or each repository you push to some central Git repository. No need for complicated stashing and such -- simply open a feature branch for each nontrivial thing you begin, commit to this feature branch, and merge when all tests succeed.

Comment: This is about the race condition between code editors and the compilers and test suite.  You can't stop editing code just because a long compile is underway, and you don't want a commit for every time you type 'make'.  I just chose rsyncing for this and it's working well:  

ie:   if I change any of the many git repos under src:    rsync src turds && ( cd turds && scons & ).

The issue is that these are changes should not be committed because they aren't known to even even compile yet.